# Unity: Performance problem build of 2D game

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, 2d

I made a simple 2D game and it works good until I build it.

In editor the game runs without any problems but when I start the .exe I've build my CPU load reaches 100% and I see a lot of lags. I've build it for Windows with x86_64 and x86 and in both builds have this issue.

Any idea why the build is extremely more laggy than in the editor and how I can fix it?

Comment: Might have a lot of reasons ... one of them might be getting a lot of exceptions in your build .

Comment: Why should I get tons of errors in build but not in editor? It doesnt use any external files, no internet etc.

Comment: maybe some of used libraries are not initialized correctly for a build? anyway its just a guess .. there are lots of other reasons .. quality settings .. etc

Comment: I havent changed any player settings, even the input setings arn't touched. I don't use any libraries and afaik unity itself should run fine :(

Comment: Tried to check for any possible memory leaks?

Comment: Asked my qustion on the unity forums too and they told me to share my log so hre it is.
https://pastebin.com/41B5qd5a
There are leaks mentioned but I have no idea where they come from, how much they cause the lags or how I can fix them.

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/jobs-lags-jobtempalloc-has-allocations-that-are-more-than-4-frames-old.513124/ This thread appears to imply it's a bug. What is your unity version?

Comment: I'm using 2019.2.5f1.
But I think the real problem is that my buld has framerates from up to 1500fps but then there are this laags (I added a FPS display) so here is what I tried to fix this (from my qustion on Unity Answers):

Comment: To limit this I tried:<br>
- Set the Application.targetFramerate once in the Start() method<br>
- Check it every Update() call andset it to 60 if it's not 60<br>
- Use QualitySettings.VSyncCount = 1<br>
but nothing locks my framerate to 60.<br>
I think this extremly useless high framerate is what my high CPU load causes. Any idea how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

So my problem is solved.
After some testing I saw that my framerate is extremely high and fluctuating.
Trying to limit it with VSync nor with targetFramerate worked.
After updating from 2019.2.5f1 to 2019.2.6f1 the problem was solved.